# Will be a support of raw sockets in node.js, e.g. to create ping packets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, raw-sockets

Will be a support of raw sockets in node.js, e.g. to create ping packets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new module named [node-raw-socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) offers the perfect solution for real raw sockets using nodejs.

And, for creating ping (ICMP) packets, the same developer has a very nice working (using it) solution based on node-raw-sockets as well: [node-net-ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping).

Comment: node-raw-socket does not install. fails on build for me.

Answer (score 5):

Node supports TCP, UDP, and unix sockets. Ping packets are ICMP packets, which node cannot create directly at this time. You could execute an external `ping` subprocess or consider writing a C extension. Most of node's low level OS APIs are thin javascript wrappers around the corresponding C API, so you could follow that existing well-established pattern and implement this as a small JS wrapper layer around the corresponding OS-level APIs.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_class_net_socket

There's a chance node/javascript are a poor choice for your project based on this requirement though.

Comment: I think the solution should be to create an addon [addons](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_addon_patterns)

Comment: @Peter, There's no reason why Node supports TCP UDP, yet doesn't support IP. Support for IP must come sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

`net-ping` module may suit your need. to install it you can use the following command:

```
npm install net-ping
```

The documentation with examples is included [here](https://npmjs.org/package/net-ping).